# Rake tasks killed unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I ran rake `import:sample_weather`, which works perfectly on my osx

But failed on my ubuntu

```
(git)-[master]
(in /www/parse_weather_sample)
[1]    1479 killed     noglob rake import:sample_weather
```

### here's my gemfile

```
% bundle list                                                                                                                                                                (git)-[master]
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.1.6)
  * actionpack (4.1.6)
  * actionview (4.1.6)
  * activemodel (4.1.6)
  * activerecord (4.1.6)
  * activesupport (4.1.6)
  * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
  * binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bundler (1.6.2)
  * celluloid (0.16.0)
  * choice (0.1.6)
  * coderay (1.1.0)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  * coffee-script (2.3.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
  * debug_inspector (0.0.2)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  * em-websocket (0.5.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * eventmachine (1.0.3)
  * execjs (2.2.2)
  * faker (1.4.3)
  * ffi (1.9.6)
  * formatador (0.2.5)
  * guard (2.8.2)
  * guard-livereload (2.3.1)
  * guard-rspec (4.3.1)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * hirb (0.7.2)
  * hitimes (1.2.2)
  * http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
  * i18n (0.6.11)
  * jbuilder (2.2.4)
  * jquery-rails (3.1.2)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * listen (2.7.11)
  * lumberjack (1.0.9)
  * mail (2.6.3)
  * method_source (0.8.2)
  * mime-types (2.4.3)
  * minitest (5.4.2)
  * multi_json (1.10.1)
  * pry (0.10.1)
  * pry-nav (0.2.4)
  * pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.1)
  * quiet_assets (1.0.3)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-mini-profiler (0.9.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (4.1.6)
  * rails-erd (1.1.0)
  * railties (4.1.6)
  * rake (10.3.2)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.5)
  * rdoc (4.1.2)
  * rspec (3.1.0)
  * rspec-core (3.1.7)
  * rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
  * rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
  * rspec-support (3.1.2)
  * ruby-graphviz (1.0.9)
  * sass (3.2.19)
  * sass-rails (4.0.4)
  * sdoc (0.4.1)
  * slop (3.6.0)
  * spring (1.1.3)
  * sprockets (2.11.3)
  * sprockets-rails (2.2.0)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.10)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread_safe (0.3.4)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * timers (4.0.1)
  * turbolinks (2.5.2)
  * tzinfo (1.2.2)
  * uglifier (2.5.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid error.

The server's memory is not enough so  the system killed my process.

Comment: How you found out that the memory was not enoguht when the process got killed?